# How to securely use IPad Pro as remote development tool?

Tags: networking, ssh

I would like to use my iPad Pro as a remote development tool for C/C++. As there is little support for running and compiling programs on iOS, I would like to try a workaround. There are IDE tools on iOS that allow ssh remote development, so I should just need a secure way to set up a ssh server.

I currently have running a Ubuntu VM (vagrant) as the compiling and execution environment. The VM has a forwarded ssh port to the host machine. I have also forwarded a port in my home router to the host machine.

I have changed the default VM user password, and used a random value for the SSH port 1024-65535. Is this method opening me up to significant security vulnerabilities on my router or host machine? Should I be using public/private ssh keys as a better security measure?

EDIT 1: I have now disabled password authentication in the SSH server after generating RSA keys (with passphrase) on a client and sending the public key to the server. Is this how it's supposed to work? Does the server not need the client's private key?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your passwords and other authentications and still can ssh to your remote server using a tool called Terminus.

I have used it alot and works like charm on all ios devices.
[TERMINUS](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/termius-ssh-client/id549039908)

Comment: Termius is what I'm using for compiling, running, and debugging! For the code editor and remote file editing, I decided to use GoCoEdit, which has been working alright so far.